# Finding last element in range() while creating sequences in python

Tags: python, time-series, lstm, sequence

I am working to create fixed size sequences from variable length CSVs.

The way I am using is a function

```
def create_sequences(csv, window_size, stride):
    sequences = []
    for i in range(0, len(csv)-window_size, stride):
        sequences.append(csv[i:i+window_size])
    return sequences
```

It successfully returns sequences but the data is lost as I have created visualization and tried to solve it manually, it is missing some data.

```
Total length = 115
Size = 30
Stride = 20
Ending size = 115 -30 = 85
First window: 0 -> 30 
Second Window: 20 -> 50
Third Window: 40 -> 70
Fourth Window: 60 -> 90
Fifth Window: 80 -> 110
```

The last five frames are lost, How can I set up a window from 100 -> 115 and pad the last row?

Answer (score 0):

Your `range()` did not include enough. You can fix the for loop as follow:

```py
def create_sequences(csv, window_size, stride):
    sequences = []
    for start in range(0, len(csv), stride):
        window = csv[start:start+window_size]
        if window == []:
            break
        sequences.append(window)
    return sequences
```

Note that within the for loop, we need to test to see if the window is empty--this happens at the end of the sequence. In that case, we know we are done with the for loop and break out.

## Update

Here is an update, which includes padding value to make all windows the same size:

```py
def create_sequences(csv, window_size, stride, padding=None):
    sequences = []
    for start in range(0, len(csv), stride):
        window = csv[start:start+window_size]
        if window == []:
            break
        if len(window) < window_size:
            window.extend((window_size - len(window)) * [padding])
        sequences.append(window)
    return sequences
```

Example usage:

```py
for window in create_sequences(list(range(115)),30, 20, padding=-1):
    print(window)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
[40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]
[60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]
[80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Comment: I want to find the last iteration and pad the sequence.

Comment: So, you want to pad the last window, with what? To make it the same size with the others?

Comment: Yes, I want to make every sequence of same size and do not miss the last sequences and pad them.